# ASP.net: using <a href> inside Label ... how can i send the session using the <a href >?

Tags: asp.net

I have a code like this :-

```
<a href ="session 2.aspx" runat="server" >
        <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</a>
```

Can I send a session using this both? because when I'm double click on the label to create a session, on the page.vb it's doesn't show any for me to create a session code..
please guys I need your help..

Comment: You don't "send" a session anywhere. Something stored in session is available site-wide.

Comment: Can I have another question.. should hyperlink need to be inside form tag.. or doesn't needed?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what your app does from the code snippet you provided? Update the original question with the info needed for people to provide you with an answer.

Comment: Please clear , what you are asking here, what will be end-result of this!

Answer (score 0):

First of all "double click on label to create session": not sure what you mean by this.

Say you want to store the value of the label in Session and retrieve it on another page:

```
Session["NameLabelText"] = lblname.Text;
```

To retrieve it:

```
var temp = Session["NameLabelText"].ToString();
```